# Which one is more efficient: tf.where or element-wise multiplication?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, loss

I'm implementing a loss function that will use a mask tensor`(M)` consisting of `0s and 1s` to eliminate some loss values given predictions`(P)` and ground-truth`(G)` tensors.

So, I have 2 possible ways:

*Element-wise multiplication:*

`loss = K.sum(M * K.binary_crossentropy(G, P))`

*Conditional selection:*

```
bin_ce = K.binary_crossentropy(G, P)
loss = K.sum(tf.where(tf.equal(M, 1), bin_ce, 0))
```

So, which will be more efficient in terms of running time?

Comment: Did you run any benchmarks yourself?

Comment: I'm running a benchmark but not finished yet. I ask for your opinion beforehand.

Comment: I'm pretty convinced that the multiplication case will be better.... waiting for the results of your tests. I can't imagine the second case using less than 2 steps.

Comment: You're right :) I did the benchmark, results are in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did the benchmark and it is quite clear that multiplication is far better than conditional selection.

Here is the results:

[image: A chart is worth a thousand words..]

A chart is worth a thousand words.

Benchmark code:

```
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import sys
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def elm(G, P, M):
        return K.sum(M * K.binary_crossentropy(G, P))

def cond(G, P, M, t):
        C = K.variable(np.zeros((t, t)))
        bin_ce = K.binary_crossentropy(G, P)
        return K.sum(tf.where(tf.equal(M, 1), bin_ce, C))


s = [100, 1000, 10000, 100000]
elms = []
conds = []

for t in s:
        print t
        t = int(t)
        # number of 1s in mask
        n = int(t/2)

        M = np.zeros((t,t))
        P = np.random.rand(t, t)
        G = np.random.rand(t, t)

        for i in range(n):
                r = np.random.randint(0, t)
                c = np.random.randint(0, t)
                M[r,c] = 1

        M = K.variable(M)
        P = K.variable(P)
        G = K.variable(G)

        start_time = time.time()
        elm(G, P, M)
        elms.append(time.time() - start_time)

        start_time = time.time()
        cond(G, P, M, t)
        conds.append(time.time() - start_time)

print elms
print conds

# create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
index = np.arange(n_groups)
bar_width = 0.35
opacity = 0.8

rects1 = plt.bar(index, elms, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='b',
                 label='Element-wise')

rects2 = plt.bar(index + bar_width, conds, bar_width,
                 alpha=opacity,
                 color='g',
                 label='Conditional')

plt.xlabel('Input tensor size')
plt.ylabel('Execution time (s)')
plt.title('')
plt.xticks(index + bar_width, ('100', '10e3', '10e4', '10e5'))
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```